# Colapsar homescreen

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy haciendo un homescreen para una aplicación y necesito que al momento de yo bajar con el scrollbar solo quede encapsulado el video, el logo y los botones de la parte inferior como muestro en la segunda imagen.

Les adjunto una foto de lo que tengo y una foto de referencia de cómo debe quedar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código css:

```
.Formulario {

  width: 380px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.cuadro_tramites {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.cuadro-scroll {
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.cuadro_scroll2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}

.cuadro-permiso-circulacion {
  height: auto;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.boton2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.label1 {
  color: black;
}

.btnEventos {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -55px;
}

.btnSolicitarInfo {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 35px;
}

.btnAudiencia {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 130px;
}

.btnConocelosP {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 230px;
}

.circulos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  right: 320px;
}

.cuadro_directo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.p_envivo {
  left: 220px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cuadrado1 {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 355px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cuadrado2 {
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: aliceblue;
  width: 355px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.label2 {
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.bienvenidx {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tramitx {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.botones_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  top: 750px;
}

.cuadro_logo {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 393px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.p_Eventos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: -55px;
}

.p_Informacion {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.p_Audiencia {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

.p_Programas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 217px;
  text-align: center;
}

.i_pcirculacion {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 20%;
}

.i_pago_derechos_aseo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 115%;
}

.i_Tramites_DOM {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 200%;
}

.i_Registro_SH {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 285%;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.contenedor_tramites {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Código html:

```
<div class="Formulario">
<div class="cuadro_tramites">
  <div class="cuadro_logo">
    <img src="imagenes/logomuni.png" width="100" height="80">
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor_tramites">
    <h3 class="bienvenidx">Bienvenid@</h3>
    <h4 class="tramitx">Selecciona el tramite que deseas:</h4>
    <div class="cuadro-scroll">
      <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
        <form action="https://home.municipalidadgorbea.cl/archivos/3118">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Permiso de circulacion</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_pcirculacion" src="imagenes/coche.png" width="200px" height="200px">
          <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="Pagar aqui">Pagar aqui</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
        <form action="https://www.sem.gob.cl/pago/buscar.php?pago_id=4&inst_id=69191200&setiframe=0">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Pago derechos de aseo</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_pago_derechos_aseo" src="imagenes/envase.png" width="150px" height="150px">
          <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="pagar aqui">Pagar aqui</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
        <form action="http://localhost:5000/TramitesDOM">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Tramites departamentos de obras</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_Tramites_DOM" src="imagenes/en-construccion.png" width="150px" height="150px">
          <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="pagar aqui">Revisar aqui</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
        <form action="https://rsh.ministeriodesarrollosocial.gob.cl/portada">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Registro social de hogares</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_Registro_SH" src="imagenes/familia.png" width="150px" height="150px">
          <button class="boton2" type="submit" value="pagar aqui">Revisar aqui</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cuadro_scroll2">
  <div class="circulos">
    <div>
      <form action="http://localhost:5000/Eventos">
        <button class="btnEventos">
          <img src="imagenes/calendario.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        </button>
        <p class="p_Eventos">Eventos</p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form
        action="https://www.portaltransparencia.cl/PortalPdT/web/guest/directorio-de-organismos-regulados?p_p_id=pdtorganismos_WAR_pdtorganismosportlet&orgcode=e1c4b38162d39">
        <button class="btnSolicitarInfo">
          <img src="imagenes/informacion.png" width="27px" height="27px">
        </button>
        <p class="p_Informacion">Solicitar informacion</p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="https://www.leylobby.gob.cl/instituciones/MU099">
        <button class="btnAudiencia">
          <img src="imagenes/hacer-clic.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        </button>
        <p class="p_Audiencia">Solicitar audiencia</p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="http://localhost:5000/ConocelosP">
        <button class="btnConocelosP">
          <img src="imagenes/usuario.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        </button>
        <p class="p_Programas">Conoce los programas</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cuadro_directo">
    <h3>Gorbea en vivo:</h3>
    <h4>
      <p class="p_envivo">En vivo ahora </p>
    </h4>
    <iframe width="350" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ceqgwo7U28Y" title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="botones_fixed">
  <button class="cuadrado1">
    <a class="label2" href="tel:452972000">Llamanos</a>
  </button>
  <form action="http://localhost:5000/FormContacto">
    <button class="cuadrado2">
      Envianos un mensaje
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas te recomendaria mirar `position: fixed` o `position: sticky` ambas son caracteristicas de `CSS`. La primera te lo ancla siempre a la ventana y la segunda lo ancla solo cuando el elemento que tiene esta caracterisitica toca un borde del navegador.

Comment: Hola, si justamente tengo el logo y los botones de mas abajo con position: fixed pero al momento de bajar con el scrollbar queda posicionada la pantalla en parte del video y parte de las demas cosas, he probado poniendo <br> para aumentar el espacio entre el video y las demas cosas para que asi al bajar solo quede este pero no funciona, la verdad no se que otras cosas intentar es por eso que queria ver si ustedes me daban alguna otra idea.